# How to set CMake Options using Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2022

I have a root `CMakeLists.txt` that contains several options, such as `option(BUILD_GUI "Build GUI Applications" OFF)`.  If I manually change the default to `ON` in this file, everything behaves as I would expect.

Additionally, if I manually set the variable on the command line using the flag `-DBUILD_GUI=ON`, everything behaves as I would expect as well.

But when using Visual Studio, I cannot figure out how to configure this option correctly.

If I right click on the `CMakeLists.txt` file there is an option for `CMake Settings for vira`, and if I click on that it creates a `CMakeSettings.json` and opens an editor to change values.  It shows a section for *CMake variables and cache*, which contains check boxes for all of my options.  If I [check one and save the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knYaR.png), Visual Studio begins running the CMake generation, however it does not actually use the value I tried to indicate in the CMake Settings window.

How do you properly configure an option like this using Visual Studio?  Am I missing a step somewhere?

I believe the issue is related to the fact that CMakeCache.txt still contains `BUILD_GUI:BOOL=OFF` and is not updating or changing.  But I'm unsure how to do that.  Even if I delete the entire `out/` directory made by Visual Studio, it appears to run the default `CMakeLists.txt` first, thus preventing me from making any changes in the `CMake Settings` window.

Comment: My recommendation: provide configuration presets which allows you to pick the desired configuration from a combo box in vs and also allows you to specify cache variables for each configuration in your `CMake[User]Presets.json` file. Just be aware that VS only supports cmake 3.20 (or 3.19) IIRC, so you cannot use all the features described here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html#configure-preset

Comment: If it's not using what you specified in a mechanism that's supposed to be used to specify such things, then isn't that a bug? I.e. I would have expected it to update any existing cache variables for reconfiguration.

Comment: I'm not sure why but if I instead click on the Configuration drop down from the top toolbar, and select `Manage Configurations...` it opens the same `CMakeSettings.json` file, but this time it appears that making changes actually does work as expected

Comment: Just FYI - VS 2022 Update 5 includes CMake 3.25.